# Is a rank means stat appropriate?

Tags: nonparametric, ranks

I have attached an image of a subset of data consisting of snow measurements (D1-D6) taken at unique locations (Site1-Site25) over the course of several years. Each measurement was taken at the same location each time, once a month for 2 years. I'm trying to convert these measurements of snow depth into a single variable for each site to represent which sites consistently have deeper snow. At this point, I don't care about differences in means or anything like that, I just would like a value for each site representing it's "relative snow depth" compared to all other sites.

So far I've essentially used a Kruskal-Wallis H-test to determine a mean rank for each site (without then conducting the test) and I'm wondering if that appropriately represents the relative snow depth I'm trying to calculate. If not, does anyone know of a test that may be more appropriate for this data? Thanks!!

[image: Snow data frame]

Comment: "measure relative snow depth" isn't a hypothesis testing problem, but an estimation problem

Comment: Is all that white space necessary on the image? Indeed, is an image needed at all - why not simply cut and paste the text and use code formatting?

Comment: Have you tried plotting the data?  If so, what did you see?

Comment: I realize this isn't a hypothesis testing problem, in fact I don't intend to generate any test statistics from this data. I already know these locations differ, I just need a way to represent a dynamic process with a static variable showing the relative differences between locations. Hypotheses will be examined later in an information theoretic approach.

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. So,  Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). Nobody are going to type in your numbers ...